# Android - Get object from AsyncTask result

Tags: java, android, object

I want to create 10 Employee objects in an AsyncTask and return the result back to the MainActivity class to print it on a ListView with the 3 attributes of an Employee object.

This is what i have so far, but it just crashes after running

Menu class

```
public class Menu 
{
    public Employee person;

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        new setEMPInfo() {
            protected void onPostExecute(Employee person)
            {
                doSomething(person);
            }   
        }.execute();
    }
    public void doSomething(Employee person) {
       //use person object to print on TextView 
    }
}
```

setEMPInfo class

```
public class setEMPInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Employee>
{
    Public Employee person;

    protected Bus doInBackground(String... params) {
        String id = "100A";
        String Fname = "John";
        String Lname = "Smith";

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            person = new Employee(id, Fname, Lname);
        }
    return person;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `onPostExecute` for getting response from `doInBackground`

Comment: What is doSomething?  your `setEMPInfo` has no constructor that takes an `Employee` object. Post the code you are using

Comment: ive updated my post to use `onPostExecute` but it just crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    setEMPInfo task = new setEMPInfo().execute();


}
private class setEMPInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Employee>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Employee> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String id = "100A";
        String Fname = "John";
        String Lname = "Smith";

        ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            person = new Employee(id, Fname, Lname);
            employees.add(person);
        }
        return employees;
    }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute( ArrayList<Employee>result)

        //print it on a ListView
        list.setAdapter(new YourAdapret(getApplicationContext(), result));

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You're returning an `ArrayList<Employee>` but you're extending `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Employee>`. You should extend `AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Employee>>` instead !

Comment: `protected void onPostExecute(Employee result)` should become `@Override protected void onPostExecute( ArrayList<Employee>result)`

Comment: thanks dude ;)  Its look like fix mistake with mistake )) i should be attentive

Answer (score 1):

when your `doInBackground` done , its return some value to `onPostExecute` . then you can do anything (save in database , save in SDcard , etc) in this method .

Answer (score 0):

You have here an example of a complete asyncTask (by google docs).

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

You can create a static object in your caller class and change it in onPostExecute for example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your class `setEMPInfo` extends `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Employee>` and not `AsyncTask<String, Void, Bus>`

The fix is to change (inside your `setEMPInfo` class)

```
protected Bus doInBackground(String... params) { ... }
```

to

```
protected Employee doInBackground(String... params) { ... }
```

and

```
public class setEMPInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Employee>
```

to

```
public class setEMPInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Employee>
```

Also, don't forget the `@Override` annotation. 
Finally, I recommend you use an IDE to automatically fix your code spelling and other common mistakes. This problem wouldn't happen in Android Studio or Eclipse. :)

So basically, your code should look like that :

**SetEMPInfo.java**

```
public class SetEMPInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Employee>
{
    public Employee person;

    @Override
    protected Employee doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String id = "100A";
        String Fname = "John";
        String Lname = "Smith";

        person = new Employee(id, Fname, Lname);

        return person;
    }
}
```

**Menu.java**

```
public class Menu
{
    public Employee person;

    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    {
        new SetEMPInfo()
        {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Employee employee)
            {
                doSomething(employee);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public void doSomething(Employee person)
    {
        //use person object to print on TextView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {


                                          new setEMPInfo() {
                                              protected void onPostExecute(Employee person) {
                                                  doSomething(person);
                                              }
                                          }.execute();
                                      }
                                  }
        );
```

here just for testing add all employee to list-

```
 public void doSomething(Employee person) {

        eList.add(person);
        Log.e("Emp->", eList.toString());
    }
```

Your AsyncTask should look like this-

```
class setEMPInfo extends AsyncTask<Employee, Void, Employee> {
        Employee person;

        @Override
        protected Employee doInBackground(Employee... params) {
            String id = "100A";
            String Fname = "John";
            String Lname = "Smith";

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                person = new Employee(id, Fname, Lname);
            }
            return person;
        }
    }
```